# Extern class in class & access

Tags: c++, class

Here's what I have now in MyClass.hpp:

```
class CLASS
{
    public:
        class AAA
        {
            public:
                char c_str[1024];
        };

        class BBB
        {
            public:
                int count;
        };
};

extern class CLASS              CLASS;
extern class CLASS::AAA         AAA;
extern class CLASS::BBB         BBB;
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
class CLASS                 CLASS;
class CLASS::AAA            AAA;
class CLASS::BBB            BBB;
```

Access to the elements:

```
AAA.c_str = 0;
BBB.count = 0;
```

But I want to get this one access variant:

```
CLASS.AAA.c_str = 0;
CLASS.BBB.count = 0;
```

... or ...

```
CLASS:AAA:c_str = 0;
CLASS:BBB:count = 0;
```

... so what I should to do with it? :c

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AAA` and `BBB` are free-standing objects, not objects inside the `CLASS` class. You have to declare the objects *inside* the `CLASS` class for it to be possible:

```
class CLASS
{
public:
    class AAA { ... };

    class BBB { ... };

    // Declare object of the above classes
    AAA aaa;
    BBB bbb;
};

CLASS cls;

cls.aaa.c_str[0] = 0;
cls.bbb.count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't because CLASS has no attribute (nor field).

You can write CLASS::AAA but NOT CLASS.AAA.

Comment: Yep, but when I'm trying to do `CLASS::BBB::count = 0;` I'm getting the error about non-static class.